# How to determinate the convergence interval D'Alembert

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to determinate the interval of convergence using the generalized criterion of D'Alembert.

Considering $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$

To determinate the interval of convergence, I did :

$R=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{nx^{n-1}}$

But I'm prety sure I'm doing something bas as I can't go further.

Comment: Did you think about the fact that your expression is the derivative (wrt $x$) of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}$ ?

Comment: The radius of convergence is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}$.

Comment: $\frac{x^n}{x^{n-1}}=x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well then the radius will be 1 then how can I find the interval ?

Comment: Yes, the radius of convergence is $1$. It is obvious that the series does not converge at $1$ or $-1$, so the interval of convergence is $(-1,1)$, or if you prefer the set of all $x$ such that $-1\lt x\lt 1$.

Comment: Still not sure on how to find the $]-1,-1[$ but I guess I'll ask my teacher for more explanation... Thanks for all.